# pandas loc error : the label not in [columns]

Tags: python, pandas

I am the beginner in Pandas, and tried to get 'Grade" columns but get the KeeyError. What am I doing wrong? Thanks

```
tdf = pd.read_csv("../data/test_csv.csv")
print(tdf.head()) 
tdf.loc[:,'Grade']
```

I want to get the Grade columns

```
   Dept   Name   Age  Grade
0   cs    kim    20      a
1   ee   park    22      b
```

KeyError: 'the label [Grade] is not in the [columns]'

Comment: Please share a sample of your csv.

Comment: Your delimiter isn't correct, maybe.

Comment: Thanks. I put space in front of Grade. Thanks